# Avoid URLs contain the language code when the used language is the default one

Tags: i18n-l10n, 10

I select the user language with the language code in the URL, as in https://example.com/zh-hans/node/1 or https://example.com/mysite.com/en/node/1.

The default language is Chinese.

How could I manage to get only https://example.com/node/1 when the selected language is Chinese?

I only get [https://example.com/zh-hans/node/1"](https://example.com/zh-hans/node/1%22). When I visit the front page and I check the links given in that page, they start with https://example.com/zh-hans/.

Is there a way to avoid seeing /zh-hans/ for the default language?

I tried playing around with the selection's rule weight, without success.

Comment: In drupal 7, Under "admin/config/regional/language" you will see the list of languages. Click the edit link to edit the languages. In the edit screen, change the "Path prefix language code". If Chinese is your default language, then keep this value blank for Chinese. Bug in drupal 10 not work,  can not chang language code.